# Google Slides script: Is it possible to script this sort of animation?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

As a social studies teacher, I am very much a newbie when it comes to scripting. However, I often do give presentations and use Google Slides mostly.

I've been wanting to accomplish something like example in the link through a script, where the last (bullet)point in the slide is highlighted and previous ones are sort of greyed out? The way I've done it now involves lots of manual clicking.

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1PCCfK6z53kT7WwNMr2Fs6ZSrrrKczmxbBUHkEXmVxDc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it is much easier (and bug-free) to do with the animate by paragraph option, without a script. [Here is an example](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1LcdtYGbSFoxBc5PNO8rtPbTO2wuZuBsFxYAmsD3fL_s/edit?usp=sharing). Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a list on a single slide (just like you already did on slide #4)
2. Right click your list
3. Click animate
4. On the sidebar to the right, tick **By paragraph**

Each paragraph (each point separated by a new line) will now appear one by one. Please let me know if [that](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1LcdtYGbSFoxBc5PNO8rtPbTO2wuZuBsFxYAmsD3fL_s/edit?usp=sharing) was the desired behavior!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I do know about that function. However, what I was aiming for the way to highlight (e.g with yellow) the last point/paragraph.